# Reading numbers from a file with lazy ByteString

Tags: haskell, file

This is my code for lazily reading a very large file which contains numbers separated by a new line character. Is there a way to simplify this using the `ByteString` module or would I have to use `Data.Text`

```
import Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as L
main = do
  contents <- L.getContents
  print (sumFile contents)
     where sumFile x = sum $ Prelude.map tups $ Prelude.map L.readInt (L.words x)
         where read' = tups.(L.readInt)


tups :: (Num a) => (Maybe (a, b)) -> a
tups (Just (a,b)) = a
tups Nothing = 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some notes.

1. bytestring's [documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.10.6.0/docs/Data-ByteString-Lazy-Char8.html) clearly states that:

> This module is intended to be imported qualified, to avoid name clashes with Prelude functions. eg.
>
> `import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as C`

This lets you unambiguously write `map` without `Prelude` qualifier.

2. There are some [properties](https://www.fpcomplete.com/user/edwardk/snippets/fmap) of `map` that allow you to write `map f . map g` as `map (f.g)`.
3. `tups` can be rewritten as one-liner with [`maybe`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:maybe) and [`fst`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fst)

   `tups = maybe 0 fst`

All of this leads to following code:

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as L
main = L.getContents >>= print . sum . map (maybe 0 fst . L.readInt) . L.words
```